# How to save the image in clipboard in variable and restore it to clipboard later?

Tags: c++, qt, clipboard, mime, qclipboard

I connect a slot to the dataChanged signal of QClipboard to store the image in the clipboard to a variable mimedata([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762140/proper-way-to-copy-a-qmimedata-object)):

```
void MyWin::clipboardDataChanged()
{
    const QMimeData * m=QApplication::clipboard()->mimeData();
    mimedata = new QMimeData();

    foreach(QString format, m->formats())
    {
        QByteArray data = m->data(format);
        if(format.startsWith("application/x-qt"))
        {
            int index1 = format.indexOf('"') + 1;
            int index2 = format.indexOf('"', index1);
            format = format.mid(index1, index2 - index1);
        }
        mimedata->setData(format, data);
    }
}
```

And restore mimedata  to clipboard as follows:

```
void MyWin::onrestore()
{
     QApplication::clipboard()->setMimeData(mimedata);
}
```

However, the data set to the clipboard seems corrupted. If I paste from the clipboard to Paint, it says "The information on the Clipboard can't be inserted into Paint." I printed the format of the data in the clipboard, i.e., "application/x-qt-image". So I think it is not a format that is supported by other applications. Is this a bug of Qt or the code is flawed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better save the whole clipboard content, so you can safely restore it when needed, i.e.

```
void MyWin::clipboardDataChanged()
{
    const QMimeData * m = QApplication::clipboard()->mimeData();
    mimedata = new QMimeData();

    for(auto format : m->formats())
    {
        mimedata->setData(format, m->data(format));
    }
}
```

Alternatively, convert the `application/x-qt-image` data into a `QImage`, then use `QMimeData::setImageData` to store it:

```
void MyWin::clipboardDataChanged()
{
    const QMimeData * m = QApplication::clipboard()->mimeData();
    mimedata = new QMimeData();

    for(auto format : m->formats())
    {
        if(format == "application/x-qt-image")
        {
            QImage image;

            QByteArray data = m->data(format);
            QBuffer buffer(&data);
            image.load(&buffer, nullptr);
            mimedata->setImageData(image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My code saves the whole clipboard content. Please forget about the code that modifies format in my code. If you press the Print-Screen key to capture an image into clipboard, the only format is "application/x-qt-image". The code modifying the format does not have any effect. The problem is when you restore the saved mimedata to clipboard later, you can not paste it to other applications.

Comment: @William I see ... can you give the alternative a try?

Comment: I tried the alternative but the result is the same. The data in the clipboard cannot be pasted to Paint. Another method is to use clipboard()->image() to save the image to a QImage object and restore it using clipboard()->setImage(), but it cannot handle with multiple components(such as images and text) in the clipboard.